# Encapsulation of two C++ classes into one high level class with performance considerations

Tags: c++, performance, class, encapsulation

I have 2 C++ classes `I1`, `I2`, implementing integer arithmetics; each one is optimized for the integer size it can handle, each one taking a specific memory size.

I would like to have some high level Integer class that encapsulates `I1`, `I2` and that I could configure at runtime (with some static method) to make it acts as `I1` or `I2`. The underlying idea is to let clients using Integer instead of `I1` or `I2`, according to the required arithmetics precision she/he defines at runtime. Note that the runtime consideration is crucial for me.

A "natural" choice would be to use dynamic allocation BUT I have a lot of instances to handle (with a lot of temporary objects) and dynamic allocation becomes time expensive.

I had a look at `boost::variant` with `I1`, `I2`, and it could fit my needs. However, it seems that the variant has the size `max(sizeof(I1),sizeof(I2))`, which is an issue for me because I need to dump the instances in file system with the appropriate size.

My question is so: is there any possibility to define such an Integer class:

- using `I1` or `I2` implementation after some runtime configuration
- using stack instead of heap (no dynamic allocation)
- using just the memory needed (`sizeof(I1)` if `I1` is used, `sizeof(I2)` if `I2` is used) and not the maximum of the two sizes.

Comment: Does this new Integer class plan to change its inner behavior (i.e switching from I1 to I2) in cases like overflows?

Comment: No, it should be configured only once at startup after reading some information in a file (this is the reason why I can't decide statically if I use `I1` or `I2`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `boost::variant`. When dumpping to the file system, instead of the variant you convert it to the contained type (either `i1` or `i2`) and dump the result. This can be done through a visitor.

**Update:** After edrezen's clarification (in a comment below).

From what I understand you want a stack-based (since dynamic memory allocations are to be avoided) discriminated union container (like `boost::variant`) called `Integer` that can hold values of type either `I1` or `I2`. In addition, if `i` is an `Integer`, then you want

1. `sizeof(i) == sizeof(I1)` if `i` holds an `I1` value; and
2. `sizeof(i) == sizeof(I2)` if `i` holds an `I2` value.

This is impossible because the size of a type is decided at compile time and cannot be changed at runtime.

The best you can have is what `boost::variant` gives, i.e., `sizeof(I) == max(sizeof(I1), sizeof(I2))`. You're probably worring too much with memory consumption and doing premature optimization. I would suggest you to go for `boost::variant`.

Comment: It could work indeed for serialization, but to be more precise, the issue with `boost::variant` in my case is the memory usage since I can really have many, many instances in memory.  Say for instance that `I1` takes N bytes in memory and `I2` takes 2N bytes. With `boost::variant`, even if I need the `I1` value, I will have 2 times the memory actually needed because `boost::variant` takes the maximum of the two sizes, which is the size 2N of `I2`.

Comment: You got the whole picture of the problem and I do agree that `boost::variant` sounds good. Nevertheless, memory consumption is really an issue and the whole available RAM may be needed. If the useful memory is reduced artificially by two, the execution time will double, which is not wanted because the algorithm takes a long time. As you said, I'm affraid it is impossible (at least with my knowledge), but I'm still trying to find some way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found some redesign choice that could work in my case. My performance issue (memory concerns and execution time) comes mainly because I want to use a generic integer class relying on one specific implementation throughout the code. In other words, I am trying to use the variant at a too low level.

Actually, my integer classes are used by an algorithm reified as a template class `Algo<T>`, the template `T` being the integer class `I1` or `I2`.

I could use the `boost::variant` with the two types `Algo<I1>` and `Algo<I2>`:

- from the client point of view, only the variant is seen, so the code is generic (except for the initialization of the variant); for instance, the `execute` method of the algorithm can be called through some variant visitor.
- memory usage is optimal because there is no variant used at low level integer arithmetic
- for the same reason, time execution is optimal because we don't have to suffer from the underlying `switch` (hardcoded inside the variant) several billions of times.

The only bad thing I can see is the need to define several variant types; actually, I have not only `Algo<T>`but also several other types depending on template `T`. For instance, I need some algorithm result type. This was the initial reason why I tried to have only one variant at a low level, but my performances concerns made me change my mind.